# how to find a string property that corresponds to a gesture.view in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a json file containing an array of dictionaries:

```
"question":"Question text",
"answers":["Yes", "No"],
"answerTracker":["1a", "1b"]
```

I have created a Question Class & an Answer Button View Class to display the questions & answers in the view.

In the view controller I have so far displayed the questions, created the answer buttons, and finally, added a tapGestureRecogniser to each button.

```
func answerTapped(gesture:UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    // Get access to the button that was tapped
    let selectionButtonThatWasTapped:SelectionButtonView? = gesture.view as? SelectionButtonView

    if let actualButton = selectionButtonThatWasTapped {

        // Find out the index for the button that has been tapped
        let selectionTappedIndex:Int? = find(self.selectionButtonArray, actualButton)

        **// Find the answer tracker for the button that has been tapped?**


        // Append the tracker for the selected button to the User Generated Code
        if let actualAnswerTracker:String = self.answerTracker as String! {

            self.userGeneratedCode.append(actualAnswerTracker)

        }
```

In the tapGestureRecognizer method above I now need to find the corresponding answerTracker (String) for the answer button that is tapped (UIView) but can't find a way? The answerTracker string corresponding to the tapped answer is to be appended into a String array property called userGeneratedCode.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have an array of answers that matches the buttons so you can use the index? If not, you should...

Comment: the array of answers in the son file match the buttons!

Answer (score 1):

you do not need to add a `tapGestureRecogniser` to a button, you can add a target and selector to button anyway. If you want to know which button is pressed, you can use tag property on `UIButton` to check against.

Comment: I thought a tapGestureRecogniser was needed? In an earlier method, where I create each of the answer buttons I've put let tapGesture:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("answerTapped:"))
            answer.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

Comment: No, you should use the code like `myButton.addTarget(self, action: "answerTapped:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)`, which is equivalent to adding a tapGestureRecogniser. To know which button was pressed, assign different tag for different buttons. like `myButton1.tag = 1 ; myButton2.tag=2;.. `so on, In `answerTapped:` method you can check the tag value to know which one is pressed.

Comment: But I'm still at a loss as to how to ascertain the 'answer tracker' for the button that is pressed.